# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in geoserver mapfish print when I enable OverviewMap in config.yaml

Tags: mapfish

I am using GeoServer mapfish print to print the map. I need to print overview map in the print layout. But I am getting the following error when I enable the **overviewMap** in config.yaml file

```
Error while generating PDF:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mapfish.print.map.MapChunkDrawer.renderImpl(MapChunkDrawer.java:86)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.tableLayout(ChunkDrawer.java:49)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:786)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1765)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:549)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:764)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1765)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:549)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:764)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:889)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:837)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:815)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ColumnsBlock$1.render(ColumnsBlock.java:67)
at org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks.addAbsoluteDrawer(PDFCustomBlocks.java:183)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ColumnsBlock.render(ColumnsBlock.java:56)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:30)
at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:175)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:370)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:184)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doPost(MapPrinterServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

config.yaml for A4 layout

```
mainPage:
  pageSize: A4
  landscape: false
  items:
    # Map Title
    - !columns
      absoluteX: 96
      absoluteY: 830
      width: 235
      items:
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 20
          align: center
          text: '${mapTitle}'
    # Map
    - !columns
      absoluteX: 12
      absoluteY: 778
      width: 403
      config:
          borderWidth: 1
          cells:
            - padding: 1
      items:
        - !map
          width: 401
          height: 712
    # Map overview
    - !columns
      absoluteX: 315
      absoluteY: 136
      width: 100
      config:
          borderWidth: 1
          cells:
            - padding: 1
      items:
        - !map
          width: 98
          height: 70
          backgroundColor: #FFFFFF
          overviewMap: 10
```

spec.json

```
{
"pages": [{
    "center": [80999.999999998, 125750],
    "langfr": "true",
    "dataOwner": "ch.swisstopo",
    "scale": 500000,
    "comment": "This is the first page selected by the user.",
    "mapTitle": "First map"
}],
"dpi": "75",
"units": "m",
"srs": "EPSG:2169",
"mapTitle": "title",
"comment":"comment",
"rotation": 0,
"minMap": "min-map-tamale.png",
"layers": [{
        "opacity": 1,
        "customParams": {},
        "type": "Vector",
        "styles": {
            "1": {
                "label": "",
                "labelSelect": true,
                "pointRadius": 6,
                "fillColor": "#ee9900",
                "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                "hoverFillColor": "white",
                "hoverFillOpacity": 0.8,
                "strokeColor": "#ee9900",
                "strokeOpacity": 1,
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeLinecap": "round",
                "strokeDashstyle": "solid",
                "hoverStrokeColor": "red",
                "hoverStrokeOpacity": 1,
                "hoverStrokeWidth": 0.2,
                "hoverPointRadius": 1,
                "hoverPointUnit": "%",
                "pointerEvents": "visiblePainted",
                "cursor": "inherit"
            },
            "2": {
                "label": "Vérité",
                "labelSelect": true,
                "fontFamily": "Courier",
                "fontColor": "#FF0000",
                "fontSize": 28,
                "fontWeight": "Bold",
                "labelAlign": "rt",
                "labelXOffset": -25,
                "labelYOffset": -25,
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "fillColor": "#ee9900",
                "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                "hoverFillColor": "white",
                "hoverFillOpacity": 0.8,
                "strokeColor": "#ee9900",
                "strokeOpacity": 1,
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeLinecap": "round",
                "strokeDashstyle": "solid",
                "hoverStrokeColor": "red",
                "hoverStrokeOpacity": 1,
                "hoverStrokeWidth": 0.2,
                "hoverPointRadius": 1,
                "hoverPointUnit": "%",
                "pointerEvents": "visiblePainted",
                "cursor": "inherit"
            },
            "3": {
                "label": "",
                "labelSelect": true,
                "pointRadius": 6,
                "fillColor": "#ee9900",
                "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                "hoverFillColor": "white",
                "hoverFillOpacity": 0.8,
                "strokeColor": "#ee9900",
                "strokeOpacity": 1,
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeLinecap": "round",
                "strokeDashstyle": "solid",
                "hoverStrokeColor": "red",
                "hoverStrokeOpacity": 1,
                "hoverStrokeWidth": 0.2,
                "hoverPointRadius": 1,
                "hoverPointUnit": "%",
                "pointerEvents": "visiblePainted",
                "cursor": "inherit"
            },
            "4": {
                "label": "",
                "labelSelect": true,
                "pointRadius": 6,
                "fillColor": "#ee9900",
                "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                "hoverFillColor": "white",
                "hoverFillOpacity": 0.8,
                "strokeColor": "#ee9900",
                "strokeOpacity": 1,
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeLinecap": "round",
                "strokeDashstyle": "solid",
                "hoverStrokeColor": "red",
                "hoverStrokeOpacity": 1,
                "hoverStrokeWidth": 0.2,
                "hoverPointRadius": 1,
                "hoverPointUnit": "%",
                "pointerEvents": "visiblePainted",
                "cursor": "inherit"
            }
        },
        "styleProperty": "_style",
        "geoJson": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "id": "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_202",
                    "properties": {
                        "_style": 1,
                        "name": "",
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [77500, 133125],
                            [68500, 122375],
                            [74250, 108625],
                            [97250, 135125],
                            [89500, 152625],
                            [89250, 152625]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "id": "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_226",
                    "properties": {
                        "_style": 2,
                        "name": "Hello",
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [77250, 101875]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "id": "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_235",
                    "properties": {
                        "_style": 3,
                        "name": "",
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [102750, 116875]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "id": "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_277",
                    "properties": {
                        "_style": 4,
                        "name": "",
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [72000, 150375],
                                [61250, 141625],
                                [65000, 134625],
                                [84500, 146875],
                                [83250, 169125],
                                [67250, 171625],
                                [63500, 157625],
                                [62500, 157125],
                                [72000, 150375]
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "name": "Cosmetic"
    },
    {
        "opacity": 1,
        "customParams": {},
        "type": "Vector",
        "styles": {},
        "styleProperty": "_style",
        "geoJson": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
        },
        "name": "OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon"
    }
],
"overviewLayers": [{
    "type": "Image",
    "baseURL": "http://geoportail-luxembourg.demo-camptocamp.com//gfx/keymap.png",
    "opacity": 1,
    "extent": [40000, 44000, 114000, 149000],
    "pixelSize": [130, 150],
    "name": "overview"
}],
"layout": "A4 portrait",
"title": "A simple example"}
```

I am using the sample spec json and config.yaml given by the mapfish print 2 samples.

Note: It is completely working if I remove the **overviewMap** parameter from the config.yaml

Any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue